# CMake linking to the result of a subshell

Tags: c++, cmake, python-c-api

I am having trouble linking python 3 in `cmake`.

The options to link in the shell are `$(/usr/bin/python3-config --ldflags)` and that works completely fine.

But when I move to `cmake`, I use:

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.5)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(sim ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
target_link_libraries(sim ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(sim ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

giving me the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.a(dynload_shlib.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I then tried

```
target_link_libraries(sim "$(/usr/bin/python3-config --ldflags)")
```

but this also does not work with error message

```
c++: error: $(/usr/bin/python3-config: No such file or directory
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--ldflags)’
```

The only method that works for me is to open the subshell by

```
echo $(/usr/bin/python3-config --ldflags)
```

> -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions

and write the content to `cmake` as

```
target_link_libraries(sim "-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions")
```

This works but the method is nasty. Is there any clean way to perform such linking?

Comment: Your glibc seems to be too old. Or maybe you have more than one glibc's in your system?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, `ldd --version` gives me `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu10) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`